# Selecting image from gallery not working in android

Tags: java, android, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I am trying to select an image from gallery to show in imageview, the selection works but the image doesn't appear in the imageview, it remains blank.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE=1;
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        //fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        //.setAction("Action", null).show();
            //}
        }//);
    public void btnClick(View v){
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECTED_PICTURE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    Uri uri=data.getData();
                    String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                    String filePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);

                    iv.setBackground(d);

                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` method

Comment: try `iv.setImageDrawable(d);` at the place of `iv.setBackground(d);`

Comment: https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker try this library it handles all the mess related to pick image or taking picture i.e permissions,orientation issues etc

Answer (score 0):

Try below code;

```
iv.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
```

instead of below code;

```
 Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);
 iv.setBackground(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example
I just try it and it's working !

http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/

Hope it helped, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem and It was caused by sometimes the filepath returned by `Uri` from `data.getData()` was null. So this causes the image to be `null`. Heres is what I did:

First I did not get the file path from `Uri` but I used the `Uri` itself to give me the image using the following method

```
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri)throws IOException{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
}
```

You can pass null in `Options`. The method throws `IOException` so make sure you catch that.
And so when you want to use it in your Image View:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(data.getData()));
```

Also remember how to resize images because a User can pick a very big image and hence takes the memory. Also modify your code to do the resizing!

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that you declared all necessary **permission** on **manifest.xml** file. Then try with it. I have edited your code -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE=1;
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        //fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        //.setAction("Action", null).show();
            //}
        }//);
    public void btnClick(View v){
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECTED_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECTED_PICTURE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
            cursor.close();
            iv. setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```